# Jquery / Javascript find closest span with custom attribute and change inner html

Tags: javascript, jquery, innerhtml

Using JQuery and/or Javascript how would I do the following -

I need to find the `<span>` which has a custom attribute equal to a certain value. I then need to set the inner `<span>` equal to some text.

Example: In the html below, I need to find the span with attribute data-my-custom-attribute == Value1 and fill the inner span with some text.

```
<span data-my-custom-attribute="Value1" >
    <span>  /**put text here***/  </span>
</span>

<span data-my-custom-attribute="Value2" >
    <span>  /**leave empty***/  </span>
</span>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "closest"? Both of your examples in your posted markup are the same distance (ancestor tree-wise) from `#MyDiv`...

Comment: Maybe I don't need 'closest' then. I will change the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this if the `div` will always be a sibling of the `span` with the attribute.

```
$('#MyDiv').nextAll('[data-my-custom-attribute="ValueX"]:first').find('span').text('something');
```

---

## After your edit

I guess you only need that :

```
$('[data-my-custom-attribute="Value1"] span').text('something');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the css siblings selector `~`

```
$('#MyDiv ~ [data-my-custom-attribute="Value1"] > span').text('BOOH!')
```

edited for selecting the inner span

Comment: I like the ~ use, but this will remove the inner span

Comment: That doesn't find the 'closest,' it finds *all* (subsequent) elements matching the selector.

Comment: OP changed completely the content of the question, now all answers had lost completely their meaning

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#MyDiv').siblings('span[data-my-custom-attribute]:first > span').text("text goes here");
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your original (and updated) question, either of these methods should work to find the `span`s:

```
// works because your custom attribute is a data attribute
$('span').filter(function (i) {
    return $(this).data('my-custom-attribute') === 'Value1';
}).children('span').text('yay! new text');

// works regardless of what the custom attribute is
$('span[data-my-custom-attribute="Value1"]').children('span').text('yay! new text');
// or
$('span[my-custom-non-standardized-html-attribute="Value1"]').children('span').text('yay! new text');
```

Here's a fiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ucq94/